# (Model.CartItems != null) Throwing Object reference not set to an instance of an object do we have any alternative to avoid this?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, view

I have an error in my partial view :  Object reference not set to an instance of an object which I tried to bybpass by adding this line but it seems not working because I got the previous mentionned error.

If I put a break point on the added line (@if (Model.CartItems != null)), the first time, the Model is not null (it contains the item I choose, I deleted it, the Model is NULL but the IF statement throw the error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I go in my web store, I selected an item and I clicked remove this item.  The item is then deleted from the cart table.  But the view is not refreshing (the item is still on the screen.  But I received a message saying the item ABC was deleted.

I added this line to try to avoid the object reference error for null but doesn't seems to be the proper command to use.  Any idea ?

```
 @if (Model.CartItems != null)
```

TableContent.cshtml  partial view

```
 @model Tp1WebStore3.ViewModels.ShoppingCartViewModel

 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Table Content";
 }

 <a Id="TableContent" href="#" class="TableContent">
   <table>
     <tr>
        <th>
            Produit
        </th>
        <th>
            Prix (unitaire)
        </th>
        <th>
            Quantite
        </th>
        <th></th>
     </tr>
     @if (Model.CartItems != null)   <====  line which I added
     {

        foreach (var item in Model.CartItems)
        {
           <tr id="row-@item.ProduitId">
               <td>
                   @Html.ActionLink(item.Produit.Description, "Details", "Produit", new { id = 
                   item.ProduitId }, null)
               </td>
               <td>
                   @item.Produit.Prix
               </td>
               <td id="item-count-@item.PanierId">
                   @item.Quantite
               </td>
               <td>
                  <a href="#" class="RemoveLink" data-id="@item.PanierId"> Enlever du panier </a>
               </td>
           </tr>
         }
    }

       <tr>
          <td>
               Total
          </td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td id="cart-total">
                @Model.CartTotal
          </td>
       </tr>
     </table>
    </a>
```

Index.cshtml   from Panier

```
 @model Tp1WebStore3.ViewModels.ShoppingCartViewModel

 @{
     ViewBag.Title = "Shopping Cart";
 }
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         $('.RemoveLink').click(function () {
             $.ajax({
                 url: '/Panier/RemoveFromCart',
                 data: { id: $(this).data('id') },
                 type: 'POST',
                 cache: false,
                 success: function (result) {
                     $('#row-' + result.DeleteId).remove();
                     $('#row-' + result.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
                     $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + result.CartCount + ')');
                     $('#update-message').text(result.Message);
                     $('#cart-total').text(result.CartTotal);
                     $.get('@Url.Action("TableContent", "Panier")')
                          $("#TableContent").html(data); });
                  },
                  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                       alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
                  }       
             });
             return false;
         });
     });
 </script>
 <h3>
     <em>Details</em> du panier:
 </h3>
 <p class="button">
     @Html.ActionLink("Checkout >>", "AddressAndPayment", "Checkout")
  </p>  
  <div id="update-message">
  </div>
  <div id="table-content">
      @Html.Partial("TableContent")    <=== partial view call
  </div>
```

PanierController.cs

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.Mvc;
 using Tp1WebStore3.Models;
 using Tp1WebStore3.ViewModels;

 namespace Tp1WebStore3.Controllers
 {
     public class PanierController : Controller
     {
         //
         // GET: /Panier/
         Tp1WebStoreDBEntities dbProduit = new Tp1WebStoreDBEntities();

         //
         // GET: /ShoppingCart/
         public ActionResult Index()
         {
             var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

             // Set up our ViewModel
             var viewModel = new ShoppingCartViewModel
             {
                 CartItems = cart.GetCartItems(),
                 CartTotal = cart.GetTotal()
             };
             // Return the view
             return View(viewModel);
         }
         //
         // GET: /Store/AddToCart/5
         public ActionResult AddToCart(int id)
         {
             // Retrieve the album from the database
             var addedProduit = dbProduit.Produits
                  .Single(produit => produit.ProduitId == id);

             // Add it to the shopping cart
             var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

             cart.AddToCart(addedProduit);

             // Go back to the main store page for more shopping
             return RedirectToAction("Index");
         }
         //
         // AJAX: /ShoppingCart/RemoveFromCart/5
         [HttpPost] 
         public ActionResult RemoveFromCart(int id)
         {
             // Remove the item from the cart
             var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

             // Get the name of the album to display confirmation
             string produitDescription = dbProduit.Paniers
                 .Single(item => item.PanierId == id).Produit.Description;

             // Remove from cart
             int itemCount = cart.RemoveFromCart(id);

             // Display the confirmation message
             var results = new ShoppingCartRemoveViewModel
             {
                 Message = Server.HtmlEncode(produitDescription) +
                     " has been removed from your shopping cart.",
                 CartTotal = cart.GetTotal(),
                 CartCount = cart.GetCount(),
                 ItemCount = itemCount,
                 DeleteId = id
             };
             return Json(results);  
         /*    return View("CartSummary");  */
         }
         //
         // GET: /ShoppingCart/CartSummary
         [ChildActionOnly]
         public ActionResult CartSummary()
         {
             var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

             ViewData["CartCount"] = cart.GetCount();
             return PartialView("CartSummary");
         }

         public ActionResult TableContent()
         {
              return PartialView("TableContent");
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov Any idea of how to resolve this situation?

Comment: First make sure that `Model==null` is false. If that's not the case what's next is using ternary syntax which sees to solve this kind of problems so instead of `@if (Model.CartItems != null)` use `@(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.CartItems) ? Something : Other thing)`

Comment: @leron  I tried the replacement solution and I got those 2 erroes: The best overloaded method match for 'string.IsNullOrEmpty(string)' has some invalid arguments   AND  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Tp1WebStore3.Models.Panier>' to 'string'

Comment: Sorry, I should see that `CartItems` is not a `string`. Still see if the ternary syntax won't help - `@(Model.CartItems == null ? Something : Other thing)`.

Comment: first time this line is working @if (Model.CartItems != null) because I choose an item in the cart.  AFter I clicked the delete , the Cart object become null (I was thinking it should be empty not null).  Then I come to this line again and I got the object reference error. I don't understand how to handle this problem. I just want to refresh the TableContent view to remove the item from the screen since it has been deleted.  Thanks